# Hibernate - Issue saving generic object to database

Tags: hibernate

I have below method to save an object to database using Hibernate but I keep getting "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Class" error while saving.

```
System.out.println("transientInstance:" + transientInstance);
System.out.println("transientInstance:" + transientInstance.getClass());  
getSession().save(transientInstance);  

System.out.println statements are printing below information.
transientInstance:class com.mypkg.pojo.Details
transientInstance:class java.lang.Class
```

Any idea what could be wrong please?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you incldue the com.mypkg.pojo.Details class - especially any association to other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to store a `java.lang.Class` object, rather than an entity instance. `transientInstance` is not an entity instance. It's `com.mypkg.pojo.Details.class`.

The error is in code that you don't show, before the call to `save()`.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get what it means the "error is before the call to save()". Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: It makes no sense to call `getSession().save(Details.class)`. Find where Details.class is passed as argument to this method, and fix the bug by passing the object rather than its class.